# Testing linear class relationship

Tags: java, class

I'm calling this *linear class relationship*, but correct me if I'm wrong. I'm looking to test whether or not the class of object `A` is an ancestor or descendant of object `B`'s class.

For example, `AbstractCollection` is linearly related to both `Object` and `ArrayList`. However, `ArrayList` is *not* linearly related to `Vector`.

My first stab was:

```
// ...Assume objects A and B were declared...

Class<? extends Object> Aclass = A.getClass();
if (Aclass.isAssignableFrom(B.getClass()) || Aclass.isInstance(B)) {
    // Their types are linearly related, at the least
}
```

Is this an appropriate check?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the question, but what's wrong with (a instanceof b || b instanceof a)?  I'm not sure bringing in the class is necessary or helpful, but there may fully be some aspect I'm missing.

Comment: As usual, I was making it too complicated. However, simply doing two instacedof tests as you stated doesn't work, since it's expecting "(object) isntanceof (type)". Aaron's solution worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test works. I prefer the symmetric check:

```
if (a.getClass().isInstance(b) || b.getClass().isInstance(a)) { 
}
```